How to locate the B008 error in Ruff when running with conda run ruff check
I’m using Ruff for linting in my project and encountered a B008 error when running the following command:
conda run ruff check --select B008 --statistics

It returns:
7       B008    function-call-in-default-argument

ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(125): `conda run ruff check --select B008 --statistics` failed. (See above for error)

However, Ruff isn’t showing me where the B008 error is located in my code, and I can’t figure out which part of the code is causing this issue. How can I find out where this error occurs so that I can resolve it? Any advice on how to make Ruff provide more details or how to manually locate the error would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT: I solved it with this command:
ruff check --select B008 . 


Use the regular expression search of your editor to find instances of something like def (.*?)\([^)]+?\( - i.e. a function definition which contains not only one open bracket (from defining the parameters), but also a second open bracket before any closing brackets. You may have to tweak this if your signature goes over multiple lines.

--statistics is the cause here. It makes Ruff shows violation counts instead of the normal output. conda run doesn't make a difference.
